# Why does Gekko_NN_TF add so many degrees of freedom?

Tags: python, optimization, gekko

I am using Gekko for trajectory optimisation. The dynamics of my system are being modelled by a NN and wrapped for Gekko. In the minimal example below I am approximating a sinusoid with the NN. Using the NN I have 1700 degrees of freedom whilst replacing it with m.sin(ctrl) leaves me with 0 DOF.

I would have assumed that the NN is immutable throughout the optimisation, why are so many degrees of freedom added?

Here is a minimal example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense

from gekko import GEKKO
from gekko.ML import Gekko_NN_TF, CustomMinMaxGekkoScaler



# generate some random sinuisodal data
X = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 1000)
y = np.sin(X) + np.random.normal(0, 0.1, 1000)


# model the data with a neural network
model = Sequential([
    Dense(16, activation='relu', input_shape=(1,)),
    Dense(1)
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse', metrics=['mse', 'mae'])


# normalise the data
X = pd.DataFrame(np.hstack([X.reshape(-1, 1), y.reshape(-1, 1)]), columns=['x', 'y'])

scaler = CustomMinMaxGekkoScaler(X, ['x'], ['y'])


history = model.fit(scaler.newdataScaled['x'].values, scaler.newdataScaled['y'].values, epochs=100, batch_size=32, verbose=0)

m = GEKKO(remote=True)

# options
m.options.NODES = 2
m.options.SOLVER = 3
m.options.IMODE = 6
m.options.MAX_ITER = 1000

m.time = np.linspace(0, 1, 101)

tf = m.FV(value=1, lb=0.1, ub=10)
tf.STATUS = 1

# wrap the model in a Gekko_NN_TF object
wrapped_model = Gekko_NN_TF(model, scaler.minMaxValues(), m, n_output=1, activationFxn='relu')

# set up state variables
x = m.CV(value=0)
u = m.CV(value=0)

# set up control variable
ctrl = m.MV(value=0, lb=0, ub=2*np.pi)
ctrl.STATUS = 1

# add equations of motion
m.Equation(x.dt() == tf * u)
m.Equation(u.dt() == tf * wrapped_model.predict([ctrl]))

# add endpoint constraint
waypoint = m.CV(value=0)
# if we've reached the waypoint, change it to 1
m.Equation(waypoint == m.if3(x - 1, 0, 1))

# fix the final value
m.fix_final(waypoint, val = 1)

# minimise final time
m.Obj(tf)

m.solve(GUI=True)
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The neural network adds degrees of freedom (1700) because of the time horizon (100 time steps) x 16 [ReLU (Rectified Linear Unit)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifier_(neural_networks)) functions that each require an additional variable for the switching condition for the `abs` statement (not sure why the extra 100 variables though). Without the switching condition, the function would not be continuously differentiable for the gradient-based optimizer. If degrees of freedom are a problem, try using function that doesn't require additional degrees of freedom such as `tanh` activation functions. Most of the extra parts of the model are removed to highlight zero degrees of freedom when using `tanh`.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense

from gekko import GEKKO
from gekko.ML import Gekko_NN_TF, CustomMinMaxGekkoScaler

# generate some random sinuisodal data
X = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 1000)
y = np.sin(X) + np.random.normal(0, 0.1, 1000)

# model the data with a neural network
model = Sequential([
    Dense(16, activation='tanh', input_shape=(1,)),
    Dense(1)
])
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse', metrics=['mse', 'mae'])

# normalise the data
X = pd.DataFrame(np.hstack([X.reshape(-1, 1), y.reshape(-1, 1)]), columns=['x', 'y'])

scaler = CustomMinMaxGekkoScaler(X, ['x'], ['y'])

history = model.fit(scaler.newdataScaled['x'].values, scaler.newdataScaled['y'].values, epochs=100, batch_size=32, verbose=0)

m = GEKKO(remote=True)

# options
m.options.NODES = 2
m.options.SOLVER = 3
m.options.IMODE = 6
m.options.MAX_ITER = 1000

m.time = np.linspace(0, 1, 101)

tf = m.FV(value=1, lb=0.1, ub=10)
tf.STATUS = 0

# wrap the model in a Gekko_NN_TF object
wrapped_model = Gekko_NN_TF(model, scaler.minMaxValues(), m, n_output=1, activationFxn='tanh')

# set up state variables
#x = m.Var(value=0)
u = m.Var(value=0)

# set up control variable
ctrl = m.MV(value=0, lb=0, ub=2*np.pi)
ctrl.STATUS = 0

# add equations of motion
#m.Equation(x.dt() == tf * u)
m.Equation(u.dt() == tf * wrapped_model.predict([ctrl]))

# add endpoint constraint
#waypoint = m.CV(value=0)
# if we've reached the waypoint, change it to 1
#m.Equation(waypoint == m.if3(x - 1, 0, 1))

# fix the final value
#m.fix_final(waypoint, val = 1)

# minimise final time
#m.Obj(tf)

m.solve()
```

To reduce the degrees of freedom for the full model, use `m.Var()` instead of `m.CV()`. Another option is to use `m.CV()` with `m.options.CV_TYPE=2` for a squared error instead of an l1-norm error that also adds additional degrees of freedom.

The number of variables and equations in the implementation of the neural network can also be reduced by switching to `Intermediate()` declarations, similar to this example:

[image: sine]

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  

# generate training data
x = np.linspace(0.0,2*np.pi,20)
y = np.sin(x)

# option for fitting function
select = True # True / False
if select:
    # Size with cosine function
    nin = 1  # inputs
    n1 = 1   # hidden layer 1 (linear)
    n2 = 1   # hidden layer 2 (nonlinear)
    n3 = 1   # hidden layer 3 (linear)
    nout = 1 # outputs
else:
    # Size with hyperbolic tangent function
    nin = 1  # inputs
    n1 = 2   # hidden layer 1 (linear)
    n2 = 2   # hidden layer 2 (nonlinear)
    n3 = 2   # hidden layer 3 (linear)
    nout = 1 # outputs

# Initialize gekko
train = GEKKO() 
test = GEKKO()

model = [train,test]

for m in model:
    # input(s)
    m.inpt = m.Param()

    # layer 1
    m.w1 = m.Array(m.FV, (nin,n1))
    m.l1 = [m.Intermediate(m.w1[0,i]*m.inpt) for i in range(n1)]

    # layer 2
    m.w2a = m.Array(m.FV, (n1,n2))
    m.w2b = m.Array(m.FV, (n1,n2))
    if select:
        m.l2 = [m.Intermediate(sum([m.cos(m.w2a[j,i]+m.w2b[j,i]*m.l1[j]) \
                                for j in range(n1)])) for i in range(n2)]
    else:
        m.l2 = [m.Intermediate(sum([m.tanh(m.w2a[j,i]+m.w2b[j,i]*m.l1[j]) \
                                for j in range(n1)])) for i in range(n2)]

    # layer 3
    m.w3 = m.Array(m.FV, (n2,n3))
    m.l3 = [m.Intermediate(sum([m.w3[j,i]*m.l2[j] \
            for j in range(n2)])) for i in range(n3)]

    # output(s)
    m.outpt = m.CV()
    m.Equation(m.outpt==sum([m.l3[i] for i in range(n3)]))

    # flatten matrices
    m.w1 = m.w1.flatten()
    m.w2a = m.w2a.flatten()
    m.w2b = m.w2b.flatten()
    m.w3 = m.w3.flatten()

# Fit parameter weights
m = train
m.inpt.value=x
m.outpt.value=y
m.outpt.FSTATUS = 1
for i in range(len(m.w1)):
    m.w1[i].FSTATUS=1
    m.w1[i].STATUS=1
    m.w1[i].MEAS=1.0
for i in range(len(m.w2a)):
    m.w2a[i].STATUS=1
    m.w2b[i].STATUS=1
    m.w2a[i].FSTATUS=1
    m.w2b[i].FSTATUS=1
    m.w2a[i].MEAS=1.0
    m.w2b[i].MEAS=0.5
for i in range(len(m.w3)):
    m.w3[i].FSTATUS=1
    m.w3[i].STATUS=1
    m.w3[i].MEAS=1.0
m.options.IMODE = 2
m.options.SOLVER = 3
m.options.EV_TYPE = 2
m.solve(disp=False)

# Test sample points
m = test
for i in range(len(m.w1)):
    m.w1[i].MEAS=train.w1[i].NEWVAL
    m.w1[i].FSTATUS = 1
    print('w1['+str(i)+']: '+str(m.w1[i].MEAS))
for i in range(len(m.w2a)):
    m.w2a[i].MEAS=train.w2a[i].NEWVAL
    m.w2b[i].MEAS=train.w2b[i].NEWVAL
    m.w2a[i].FSTATUS = 1
    m.w2b[i].FSTATUS = 1
    print('w2a['+str(i)+']: '+str(m.w2a[i].MEAS))
    print('w2b['+str(i)+']: '+str(m.w2b[i].MEAS))
for i in range(len(m.w3)):
    m.w3[i].MEAS=train.w3[i].NEWVAL
    m.w3[i].FSTATUS = 1
    print('w3['+str(i)+']: '+str(m.w3[i].MEAS))
m.inpt.value=np.linspace(-2*np.pi,4*np.pi,100)
m.options.IMODE = 2
m.options.SOLVER = 3
m.solve(disp=False)

plt.figure()
plt.plot(x,y,'bo',label='data')
plt.plot(test.inpt.value,test.outpt.value,'r-',label='predict')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, that makes a lot of sense.